# Powershell Get-ADUser from Dev, Test and PROD

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I am bit new to power shell scripting which is best to specify the environment details (dev, test and Prod) to retrieving the data for AD group/users and updating the AD users/group details?. Any sample code will help. Thank you in Advance.

Comment: what version of PoSh are you working with? it's usually best to specify the _lowest_ version you need to be compatible with. ///// also, what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would do is install the ActiveDirectory PowerShell module.

Different environments like dev, test, prod, etc. usually mean there are dedicated Active Directory instances for each. The AD instances will be distinguishable either by their domain name or the group of domain controllers that replicate that particular instance's data.

If you have a dedicated domain for each environment, most of the commands in the ActiveDirectory module allow you to specify a search base or server name. The `SearchBase` parameter allows you to enter a distinguished name string for an OU or just the root domain component. The `Server` parameter allows you to pass the name of a domain controller. Using those two parameters, you can segregate search queries and write operations across multiple environments.

**Example 1: dev.local Domain**

The following will return all AD users of the dev.local domain:

```
Get-ADUser -filter * -SearchBase "dc=dev,dc=local"
```

**Example 2: dc1.test.local Domain Controller**

The following will return all AD groups that are in the AD database of dc1.test.local:

```
Get-ADGroup -filter * -Server dc1.test.local
```

The same methods can be applied to commands that write back to AD.

If you have different environment data within the same Active Directory, you can use a similar approach in **Example 1**. If your environment data is within a distinguishable OU structure, you can rely on the `-SearchBase` parameter again. You could also tag your objects by adding identifiable data to object attributes. Those attributes can be referenced when running commands like `Get-ADUser` or `Get-ADGroup`. Another way is to put test objects into AD groups that you can clearly identify. Then you can query those groups first to retrieve your test objects.

You can learn a lot just by reading command capabilities at [Get-ADUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser?view=win10-ps) and [Get-ADGroup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-adgroup?view=win10-ps). The `Get-Help` command can provide helpful examples also.

Comment: Additionally, I use `Get-ADUser -Identity "SamAccountName"` or `Get-ADUser -Filter "DisplayName -eq 'Display Name'"` a lot. Make sure you are aware of the limited properties that are returned. To get all the properties include the `-Properties *` switch. eg: `Get-ADUser -Filter "DisplayName -eq 'Ross Lyons'" -Properties *`. Give it a go to see the results and try it out.

Comment: Thank you very much, That was helpful :)